# Add a client application to Azure Active Directory application fails in the "Expose Api" blade

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I try to add a client to my Application, I get the following error:

> Failed to update application property. Error detail: Property
>   preAuthorizedApplications.appId has an Application Identifier that
>   cannot be found.

I selected the right scope and generated a new GUID for my client id. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Client ID` should be the one of an existing AD App, not the new generated GUID.

Change it then will work fine.

[image]